# Replace DOM element in Vue after split

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my array in vue:

```
 data: {
        my_list: [
            { "text": "Whoever is Silent. He is Saved", "emphasizes": "Silent, Saved", "link": "website" },
            { "text": "If you don't value yourself, who will", "emphasizes": "value, self", "link": "twitter" },
        ],
    }
```

and this is my html

```
<li v-for="texts in my_list">
      {{ texts.text}} ({{ texts.emphasizes }}) {{ texts.link }}
</li>
```

I want to repalce the texts of `{{ texts.text }}` which match `{{ texts.emphasizes }}` when splited along with some **HTML**

Comment: And what is your question? If you modify the items of the array, all template expressions should update automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `v-html` for displaying and use `methods` to replace.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
   data: {
        my_list: [
            { "text": "Whoever is Silent. He is Saved", "emphasizes": "Silent, Saved", "link": "website" },
            { "text": "If you don't value yourself, who will", "emphasizes": "value, self", "link": "twitter" },
        ],
    },
    methods:{
      replaceText: function(str,replaceText){
        var replaceArr = replaceText.split(',');
        for(let i in replaceArr){
          str = str.split(replaceArr[i].trim()).join('<strong>'+replaceArr[i].trim()+'</strong>');
        }
        return str;
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<ul>
<li v-for="texts in my_list">
      <span v-html="replaceText(texts.text,texts.emphasizes)"></span> ({{ texts.emphasizes }}) {{ texts.link }}
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```